# Wiring 2 ac to DC power adapters together

Tags: power-supply

I have a mini amp and several powe adapters. Can I wire 2 6 volt DC power supplies together for the required 12v DC the amp needs? If so, how? And it suggests 2 amps. Are amps cumulative, and does it matter if they are different? the only relevant video i could find on you tube didnt quite fit my situation and i ended with more questuins than answers

Comment: This question is about series connection, the other one about paralleling of sources with different voltages. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @OlafM The other is about series connection as well - the question there was to combine a 5V and a 15V source to generate a 20V source - that is a series connection. (Actually they want to get both as the current should also increase)

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably get downvoted but anyway, if you attempt it...

1. **Use the same type and model of power adapter. (Make sure each can handle at least 2 Amps**)
2. Cut both barrel plug off the both adapters.
3. Connect one GND to one 6V output.
4. Connect other GND back to barrel plug.
5. Connect other 6V (now 12V with reference to the GND you just hooked up) to the barrel plug.

Comment: Isn't this only possible if the GNDs are galvanically isolated to each other? Otherwise you will short one adapter because it will have a return path trough the other adapter. I could be wrong though.